# derived table with alias

Tags: sql, teradata

```
select fullcount.c1, internalcustomers.c2, anonymousTransid.c3, companyNo.c4
from (
select count(*) as c1 
from Customer
WHERE CustomerID not in (select CustomerID from Address)
) as fullcount
join
(
select count(*)  as c2
from Customer
where trim(firstname) not between '0' and '9999999999999999'
and CustomerID not in (select CustomerID from Address)
) as internalcustomers
on  fullcount.c1 = c2.customerid
```

and

```
(
select count(*) as c3
from Customer
where trim(firstname) between '0' and '9999999999999999'
and CustomerID not in (select CustomerID from Address) 
)as anonymousTransid
join
(
select count(*) as c4 
from Customer
where trim(firstname) not between '0' and '9999999999999999'
and iscompany like '%n%' 
and CustomerID not in (select CustomerID from Address) 
)as companyNo
on anonymousTransid.c3=companyNo.c4
```

assigned alias to my calculated column and to my derived table.. saw this on another forum but i cant get my query to run

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: As all SELECTs return only a single row you can simply use a CROSS JOIN, so you don't need an ON-condition